# How to remove port number in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I've just begin in node.js. I made quite nice script but I have one think what I can't resolve.

How to remove port number what I see in firebug (this port I used to establish connection)

In picture in red frame I marked this port what I'd like hide from user/firebug

[screen of the picture http://www.imagesup.net/?di=814044803130](http://www.imagesup.net/?di=814044803130)

Comment: The reason why the port is being shown is because 7777 is not a standard HTTP or HTTPS port.  Use port 80 for a non-secure connection and port 443 for a secure connection.

Comment: 80 and 443 can't use becouse is busy from apache service

Answer (score 0):

I think that firebug will allways show the post info, one solution would be to use websocket to send the data